# How to create a dynamic amount of sub domain with Route53 in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I need to create a dynamic number of subdomains depending on how many instances I want to create. my goal id to create something like

- customer-code-100.example.com
- customer-code-101.example.com
- customer-code-102.example.com
- customer-code-103.example.com

I've researched, but there doesn't seem to be a solution. I need to be able to run Puppet on multiple hosts, but they each need a different domain.

Ideally, I want to be able to use autoscaling or some sort of dynamic way to accomplish this, but I haven't been able to find any answers.

```
MyRecordSet: 
   Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
   Properties: 
     HostedZoneName: example.com.
     Name: !Join[".", [!Ref Alias, "example.com"]]
     Type: A
```

Comment: What is your particular use-case for requiring a subdomain for each instance? Normally, access would be via a Load Balancer.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for the explanation under the answers. This use case is to separate each customer and by availability zones. We also need to use Puppet, but since Puppet is certification based, we need a unique domain for each of the hosts. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easier method is to **have the instances register themselves with Amazon Route 53**. This can be done with a startup script that uses the AWS CLI to register a domain name.

Admittedly, it can be hard to decide which number to assign an instance, especially if Auto Scaling is being used. For example:

- If `Instance 1` and `Instance 2` exist, obviously the next is `Instance 3`
- But if `Instance 2` is terminated by Auto Scaling and only `Instance 1` and `Instance 3` exist, should the next instance be `Instance 2` or `Instance 4`?

Or, use part of the Instance ID to generate the name.

Then there is the problem of "unregistering" a subdomain when the instance is terminated.

Actually, there **should normally be no need to assign a subdomain to an Auto Scaling instance**. This is because traffic is normally routed through a Load Balancer, or the instances are pulling work from a queue. There should be no need to uniquely address a specific instance.